ffmpeg hardware vaapi encoding VC1 to H.265
I am trying to transcode a video from VC1 to H.265 using hardware acceleration. VC1 by software decode and then encode by hardware acceleration.
ffmpeg  -i title_t01.mkv  -map 0   -c:a copy  -c:s copy   -c:v hevc_vaapi  DUMB_AND_DUMBER.mkv

Unfortunately this does not work
detected 16 logical cores
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55bc75120200] Setting 'video_size' to value '1920x1080'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55bc75120200] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55bc75120200] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/1000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55bc75120200] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55bc75120200] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '24000/1001'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55bc75120200] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000 fr:24000/1001 sar:1/1
[format @ 0x55bc75120a40] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'vaapi'
[auto_scale_0 @ 0x55bc750eae80] w:iw h:ih flags:'' interl:0
[format @ 0x55bc75120a40] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale_0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[vf#0:0 @ 0x55bc751182c0] Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
[vist#0:0/vc1 @ 0x55bc751134c0] Decoder thread received EOF packet
[vist#0:0/vc1 @ 0x55bc751134c0] Decoder returned EOF, finishing
[vist#0:0/vc1 @ 0x55bc751134c0] Terminating decoder thread
Error while filtering: Function not implemented

